# requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager when running android app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When running an application on android i get this error. It builds correctly but crashes with exception. I have installed React-native-screens, @React-native/navigation and the dependencies listed on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

```
This error is located at:
    in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig
    in Unknown
    in RNSScreen
    in N
    in ForwardRef
    in y
    in E
    in RNSScreenStack
    in w
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider
    in Unknown
    in v
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in ForwardRef
    in Unknown
    in ForwardRef
    in p
    in c
    in P
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in h, stack:
```

It builds and runs on iOS fine but when running on android it crashes completely. Is there something I am overlooking here?

This is my Package json.

```
{
  "name": "<myprojectname>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify",
    "android:bundle:debug": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "adbkit": "^2.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.63.0",
    "react-native-calendar-strip": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.264.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.1.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I dont really know how to solve this, have tried removing caches, restarting metro, deleting node modules and all "related" errors. This error even happens when I create a fresh project and try installing and using the navigation library.

This is my entrypoint, example copied from React-navigation snack.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';

enableScreens(true);
function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AppTest() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator 
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen  options={{ title: 'My home' }} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen  options={{ title: 'My home' }} name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppTest;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you found the solution? I get the same error and i tried all answers but didnt work.

Comment: You need to re-execute this command : `npx react-native run-android` to resolve and configure react-navigation modules.

Answer (score 63):

If someone ends up here with this issue while using nrwl/nx mono-repo for cross-platform build (mobile and web), you need to add the `react-native-screens` and `react-native-safe-area-context` dependency in the mobile application package.json besides the workspace package.json.

Comment: This is the final NX repo solution. I tried every other solution and none of them worked.

Comment: This worked, IN ADDTION to running `pod install` (after the commands above) and within  the iOS dir (for iOS only obviouisly), deleting the app from the device, and then rebuilding

Comment: This is not the complete answer unfortunately, since you need to make sure to delete any old package-lock.json / yarn.lock / Podfile.lock files from previous installations. In addition, you have to run npm start --ios --clean-cache to drop old  npm cache files.

Comment: It worked for me just by adding them to the package.json of the app. I use "@nx/react-native": "17.2.7" and building for android.

Answer (score 34):

I faced this issue on ios during my work on navigation.

I'm not sure what exactly solved the issue. I reinstalled all the navigation packages and ran `npx pod-install`, cleaned metro cache, build data, derived data and the error disappeared.

Comment: This is so useful to me for ios issue.

Also, I did 'cd ios' and 'bundle install', 'npx pod-install'

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton Aliaksei - you've solved another of the many dependency issues not handled well (at all)...

Answer (score 24):

Solution have in documentation of [reactnavigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

After install `@react-navigation/native` you have to install two dependency:

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

it's mention library.

**NB:** **`react-native-screens`** package requires one additional configuration step to properly work on **Android devices**. Edit `MainActivity.java` file which is located in

`android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java.`

Add the following code to the body of MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
}
```

and make sure to add an import statement at the top of this file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Answer (score 18):

You just need to make sure installing the dependencies after installing stack
on windows run this code:

> npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score 14):

Kill Metro and clean gradle build (it might take a minute or two):

```sh
cd android
.\gradlew clean
```

Start Metro and clear cache:

```sh
npm start --reset-cache
```

Recompile

```sh
npm run android
```

---

Also, make sure in `MainActivity.java` you have added `import android.os.Bundle;` BELOW `package com.your_package_name`. Description on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/ for some people might suggest to put it on very top of this file, but this is wrong thinking. This is how it should look like:

```java
package com.your_package_name;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Comment: on win10 npx react-native start  --reset-cache was enough

Comment: Recompiling (`npm run android`) did the trick for me

Comment: Note it should be ./gradlew clean. Not .\gradlew clean if I am not mistaken

Comment: This killed my app, no idea how to fix now.

Answer (score 12):

i encountered the same issue ater Editing `MainActivity.java` file which is located in `android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java`
while following [react-navigation-getting-started-guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

you need to stop the metro-server

and then, run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I just reloaded my emulator via xCode and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem after setting up navigation for ios. Here is the solution I found:

1. In the terminal, run `npx pod-install ios` because [as explained in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project), "If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you need to install the pods (via Cocoapods) to complete the linking."
2. Quit my simulator
3. Terminated and re-ran `npx react-native start`
4. Terminated and re-ran `npx react-native run-ios`

After completing these steps the app ran successfully again.

Comment: Thanks. Out of all the answers, this helped me fix the error.

Answer (score 5):

If this issue persists even after running `npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`, try:

```
cd ios >> pod install and try react-native run-ios again
```

Answer (score 4):

[Mihir Panchal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16819973/mihir-panchal) Thanks for the reply but I found a solution myself.

SOLUTION.

I followed the instructions in the documentation. Did not work any differently.

I saw that some projects where imported in these 3 files:
settings.gradle, app/build.gradle and mainactivity.java
ex.

Settings.gradle:

```
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-screens'
project(':react-native-screens').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-screens/android')
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')

include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include (':react-native-safe-area-context')
project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android')
include ':app'
```

...

app/build.gradle

```
  implementation project(':react-native-screens')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')
```

and finally in my mainApplication.java

```
  @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new AsyncStoragePackage(),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
            new RNFirebaseLinksPackage(),
            new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
            new ReanimatedPackage(),
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
            new RNScreensPackage(),
            new SafeAreaContextPackage()
      );
    }
```

To get the librarys to work and everything to be setup it had to be linked here.
Don't know if this helps anyone but I was stuck for some time and doing this made the application work as expected. Might be easy to miss if you are not experienced(I am not very experienced with RN)

Comment: this is not a solution, what to do with this information?

Comment: I started facing this issue after upgrading my MacOS to 13.1 (Ventura). This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Did you make the changes given in the documentation?
As per this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/
you need to make changes in `MainActivity.java` which is located in `android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java`

Add this at the very start of the file `import android.os.Bundle;`

and then add `@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(null); }`

Once again go through the documentation

Comment: That did it, yes... but FFS, the couldn't come up with a more meaningful error message?

Answer (score 2):

I had same error. Try this.

if you using ios

1. cd ios in your root folder
2. pod install
3. cd ..
4. yarn or npm ios. Again build.

if you using android

- in mainactivity.java file
- copy

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
  }
  and

  import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`npm install react-native-screens`

`npm install react-native-safe-area-context`

Installing the above packages through should solve your problem. Try installing using `--force` flag. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
1- npm install @react-navigation/native
2- npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
3- react-native run-android
```

if still not working, then try:

```
1- cd android
2- ./gradlew clean
```

then try the above 3 steps again I hope it will work then.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check Your OS

If You are Using Mac,
you need to install the pods (via Cocoapods) to complete the linking.

```
npx pod-install ios
```

This will Definitely resolve you issue in MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Add in   "settings.gradle"

```js
include ':react-native-screens'
project(':react-native-screens').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native- 
screens/android')
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native- 
reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture- 
handler/android')
include (':react-native-safe-area-context')
project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area- 
context/android')
include ':app'
```

```
add in "app/build.gradle"
```

```js
implementation project(':react-native-screens')
implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')
```

```
Just Making above only 2 changes  your project will work fine. 
Thanks....
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fix the issue, and this issue is an manual linking issue actually.

Following previous answers is not enough.

Here is my complete changes.

```
// settings.gradle

include ':react-native-screens'
project(':react-native-screens').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-screens/android')
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include (':react-native-safe-area-context')
project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android')
```

```
//app/build.gradle

dependencies {
...
    implementation project(':react-native-screens')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')

}
```

And one more step.

```java
//MainApplication.java

@override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages(){

    ...
    packages.add(new com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage());
    //My Metro told me that RNGestureHandlerPackage is created twice, hence I comment the line, and then everything works.
    // packages.add(new com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage());
    packages.add(new com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage());
    packages.add(new com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage());
```

ref: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/684

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **@react-navigation/native-stack**, you should install **react-native-screens** and **react-native-safe-area-context too**. I believe your error is because you don't have installed react-native-screens

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error finally I made a success by following the solution.

```
npm install react-native-screens 
npm install react-native-safe-area-context
```

install both modules in root folder or If you use microapp architecture install this inside your example folder too. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you need to install the pods (via Cocoapods) to complete the linking.

> npx pod-install ios

This is in the react-navigation/native documentation
[Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project)

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWrR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWrR.png)]

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I realize this post is for android, but I'm wondering if it is an issue with installing the cocoa pods after talking to a colleague about this issue.

Hope you all are well! I too, was having this and wanted to add what worked for me. I'm working on a RN project with my first gig outta bootcamp, so I'm also pretty new to these builds. However, it's my understanding that anytime you run `pod install` you need to run the project from xcode in order to link the pods with node_modules.

To do this you'll want to:

- Run xcode
- Go to your project folder in question
- Go to ios folder
- Open `<project_name>.xcworkspace`
- Click the play button on the top left to build the project (If you have a simulator selected, it should open the app once built)

After finishing these steps, I no longer had that error message.

Comment: Note, said colleague mentioned: "Anytime you see “not found in UIManager” run the project from xcode".

Answer (score 0):

Changing `settings.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` was not enough. The following changes to `MainApplication.java` are needed:

```
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
    packages.add(new com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage());
    packages.add(new com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage());
    packages.add(new com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage());
    packages.add(new com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage());
```

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. stop you metro connection
2. restart you app

Then it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I face same Issue,
so you just have to close project from emulator. and re-run .Error gone

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31520179)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the updated dependencies for `react-navigator` haven't been bundled into the app.
On `Android`, re-install the app by running

```
react-native run-android
```

and this error vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use all clearance commands and restart metro, it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 4 steps. I resolved the same issue.

```
cd android 
.\gradlew clean 
npm start --reset-cache 
npm run android
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday even tho i already had react-native-screens installed and i solved it by running the following commands

```
npm uninstall react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli --force
```

then i did this this command

```
npm install react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli --force
```

after that i ran npm run android and it workede

Answer (score 0):

> Add this line in MainActivity.java file in the bottom of
> "getMainComponentName" function

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
```

> also Import

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
```

> add this line in android/build.gradle

```
ext{
...
  kotlinVersion = "1.4.10"
}
```

> then clean the gradlew and run the project

Answer (score 0):

For android emulators
I solved it in this way:
1- close metro
2-go to android and write: .\gradlew clean
delete already build app from emulator.
3- run  npx react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem due to expo linking. I went through [this doc](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#automatic-installation) and uses the automatic linking. Might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was using expo and got this error.
All packages were installed normally.
The problem is that I ran into an environment different from expo-go because I was using dev-client.
If you are using dev-client, delete the build file, rebuild it, and run dev-client again.

this method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I did everything recommented by [official docs of React Navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) but it was still giving this error.

In my case I was doing the adb reverse which was causing the issue.

I uninstalled the app from device and reinstalled. It worked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER:* I encountered this issue when scaffolding a monorepo framework using Nx (`@nx/react-native`) recipe. Specifically when setting things up with `@react-navigation/native` npm package installation. If you are coming here for the same reason, then keep reading. Otherwise, read from **Case-2: Bare React native app** and after

### Case-1: Nx Monorepo issue

1. First, make sure you delete any old .lock files:

On the root directory of your Nx monorepo, run

`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`

Then change directory inside your app that you want to run and do the same (Nx does that for you but just in case there is any leftover files):

`rm -rf node_modules`

Then inside your `/ios` directory run:

`rm -rf /Pods Podfile.lock`

2. Then you need to make sure you clean your npm cache:

Go back to your project root and run:

`npm cache clean --force`

3. As described in their official documentation, for [`@react-navigation/native`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) you  need to also make sure you install peer dependencies, like so (I use npm)

```
npm i --save react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Or if you are using yarn do the same.

Don't forget to also include them as dependencies inside the `package.json` file of your app! This will take care of the installation of your npm packages inside your monorepo, as well as the app /node_modules.

Then you need to make sure you run the app with the reset flag like so:

`npx nx serve <app> --reset-cache`

Nx takes care of the Pods installation as well.

---

### Case-2: Bare React native app

1. Make sure you delete any old .lock files:

From the root directory of you app, run

`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`

Then inside your `/ios` directory run:

`rm -rf /Pods Podfile.lock`

2. Then you need to make sure you clean your npm cache:

Go back to your application root and run:

`npm cache clean --force`

3. As described in their official documentation for [React Navigation 6.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) you  need to also make sure you install peer dependencies, like so (I use npm)

```
npm i --save react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Or if you are using yarn do the same.

Then you need to make sure you run the app with the reset flag like so:

`npx run start --ios --reset-cache`

Hope this solution covers both cases and helps you all.

Answer (score 0):

Error => Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

resolve=>   **npm install react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli --force**

and restart running react native apps

it's working fine

Answer (score -1):

```
yarn add react-native-screens
```

or

```
npm i react-native-screens
```

Answer (score -2):

Install react-native screens and that should resolve the issue.

`yarn add react-native-screens`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).