# i am facing issue in react native when i started learning navigation it i applied and error came

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am facing issue in react native when I started learning navigation it I applied and error came

[image: the error image is here]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { View, Button ,Text } from 'react-native';
import Home from './src/home';
import ProfileScreen from './src/Profile';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
    return (<
        NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home"component={Home}  options={{ title: 'Welcome' }} /> 
                     </Stack.Navigator>
             </NavigationContainer>
             );   
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager when running android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana)

Answer (score 0):

**run this command**

```
 npm pod-install
```