# requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to fix this error requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager. in windows pc i have tried @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(null);
}  but it didnt work and also tried .\gradlew clean  both are not working in my case than how to fix it>

## my package.json

```
{
  "name": "letschat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill Metro and clean gradle build (it might take a minute or two):

`cd android`

`.\gradlew clean`

Start Metro and clear cache:

`npm start --reset-cache`

Recompile

`npm run android`