# React Native Android - "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to follow this tutorial [Navigating Between Screens](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) to use react-navigation.
I am making a React Native application using Expo on MacOS and am trying to run it on the Android emulator.
My code is exactly the same as in the documentation linked above.
However, I get the following error after running my application:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.
```

I tried doing everything [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana) mentions:

- The libraries were already installed but I tried reinstalling them without success.
- The code to add to the MainActivity.java was already in the file.
- I tried re running the application using `npx expo run:android` and `npx expo start`
- I tried cleaning everything using `./gradlew clean` and rebuilding as well as clearing the cache.
- I tried restarting VSCode as well as my computer without success.

Would any of you have an idea what could be the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly shows up when the react navigation's dependencies are not installed properly or not installed at all. You can try using the below code in your terminal and run the app again after installing these dependencies.

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

It should solve your problem!!

Comment: I did try that as it was suggested in the StackOverflow link I mentioned but it does not change anything sadly...

Comment: Try uninstalling the package, it may help... and then installing them.