# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager. in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When running an application on Android, I receive an error. It builds correctly but crashes with an exception.

I don't know how to solve this. I have tried removing caches, restarting Metro, deleting node modules, and all related errors. This error even occurs when I create a fresh project and attempt to install and use the navigation library.

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

```
This error is located at:
    in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
    in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Igttaskk(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Comment: Have you checked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043806/requirenativecomponent-rnsscreenstackheaderconfig-was-not-found-in-the-uimana)?

Comment: "resolve this error asap"—please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.) And please read [ask]. This question isn't at all clear.